# Help needed in finding cardinality of the Ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

> Edit : I rechecked the question again and I couldn't find any error except that I should have written  $\mathbb{Z[x]} $ instead of $\mathbb{Z} $.So, I hope question would be fine now.

I am trying assignment problems of abstract algebra and I was unable to solve this particular problem.

> Let R be the ring $\frac{\mathbb{Z[x]}} {((x^{2}+x+1) (x^{3} +x +1)) }$and I be the ideal generated by 2 in R. Then what is cardinality of R?

Unfortunately I am clueless on this particular question and don't know where to start so I am unable to show attempt made to solve the problem.

Can anyone please help.

Comment: $R$ is infinite. Do you mean $R/I$?

Comment: As written, $(2)$ is certainly at *most* countable, so it remains to show $(2)$ is not finite.

Comment: You may as well delete the [previous version of this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3778919/29335) since no answers were proffered.  If someone had answered there, you'd leave it open, though, and put a pointer from here to there for context.

Comment: You still haven't addressed the other comment in the first question though: what does $I$ have to do at all with the cardinality of $R$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the question is asking for $|R/I|$ then:

The polynomials $x^2+x+1,x^3+x+1$ are coprime in $\mathbb{F}_2[x]$, so by the Chinese remainder theorem: $$R/I\cong\frac{\mathbb{F}_2[x]}{(x^2+x+1)(x^3+x+1)}\cong\frac{\mathbb{F}_2[x]}{(x^2+x+1)}\times \frac{\mathbb{F}_2[x]}{(x^3+x+1)}.$$

Both of $x^2+x+1,x^3+x+1$ are irreducible over  $\mathbb{F}_2$ (it suffices to check that $0,1$ are not roots) so we get:$$R/I\cong \mathbb{F}_4 \times \mathbb{F}_8.$$

Thus $|R/I|=4\times 8=32$.

Comment: I think you took $\mathbb{ F_{2}[x] } $ as 2 is ideal . Hope I am right?

Comment: @YannicMuller I am assuming you wish to compute the cardinality of $R/I$, which is a quotient of $\mathbb{F}_2[x]$.  That is $\mathbb{Z}[x]/(2)=\mathbb{F}_2[x]$.

Comment: @YannicMuller Yes exactly.